# How to give a Json array an Identifier in golang

Tags: arrays, json, go, struct

I am trying to create a JSON array in Go with a struct using `json.Marshall` however I cant seem to get the desired result here is the slice of structs I am working with.

```
posts := []models.Post{
    models.Post{Id: 1,MediaUrl:"...", Title: "...", Slug: "...", ShortDescription : "...", Content : "..."},
    models.Post{Id: 2,MediaUrl:"...", Title: "...", Slug: "...", ShortDescription : "...", Content : "..."},
}
```

And I am trying to marshall it into a struct that looks like

```
{"posts":[{"Id": 1,...},{"Id": 2,...}]}
```

But I am stuck at

```
[{"Id":1,...},{"Id": 2,...}]
```

I dont know how to get the additional `{"posts":..}` around the json array.
How do I add this additional identifier to the json array?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the slice with a struct to add the JSON object with "posts" field:

```
data := struct { 
   Posts []models.Post `json:"posts"`
}{
   Posts: posts
}
p, err := json.Marshal(&data)
```

An alternative is to wrap the slice with a map:

```
p, err := json.Marshal(map[string]interface{}{"posts": posts})
```

Comment: You are awesome